# SQL Server: how to execute query with cursor inside stored procedure and how to pass a list of params to the stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I am trying to write a stored procedure in SQL Server which will:

- Take a list of integers as input ( let's assume these integers are "profile_id")
- pick up all the table names which has a column named as "profile_id" into a cursor
- loop through the cursor and print the profile_id value when it matches one of them in the input list of params.

Now the problem is: I am executing the procedure like this:

```
EXEC dbo.de_dup '1234,2345';
```

and getting a syntax error when trying to execute the commented out line below (Please see the procedure):

```
set @id = (select profile_id from @tname where profile_id in @a_profile_id );
```

Questions:

1. What would be the right way of executing and setting the value inside a cursor?
2. What is way (in our case) to pass a list of integers to this procedure?

This is my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.de_dup
    (@a_profile_id nvarchar(MAX)) 
AS
    DECLARE @tname VARCHAR(max),
            @id int;

    DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT 
            a.TABLE_CATALOG +'.'+a.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.'+ a.TABLE_NAME AS table_name
        FROM 
            JobApp.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            JobApp.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS b ON a.TABLE_CATALOG = b.TABLE_CATALOG
                                              AND a.TABLE_SCHEMA = b.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                              AND a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME
        WHERE 
            a.COLUMN_NAME = 'profile_id'
        GROUP BY 
            a.TABLE_CATALOG, a.TABLE_SCHEMA, a.TABLE_NAME, a.COLUMN_NAME;

    OPEN tables_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @tname;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @a_profile_id ;
        PRINT @tname ;
        --set @id= (select profile_id from @tname where profile_id in @a_profile_id );
        --PRINT 'id : ' + @id;

        FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @tname;
    END;

    CLOSE tables_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE tables_cursor;
GO;
```

Please let me know should I provide more clarification. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first question and s why do you want to use a Cursor.

Comment: This is simplest example that I provided that we would do with cursor. We will do much more complex thing with each table name

Comment: can you please post the error? when you want to execute a query where the table name is in a variable, you need to use the dynamic SQL concept

Comment: You want the profile id's to be just printed? what is the `sql-server` version?

Comment: we want to use incoming profile ids to be used in the query : (select profile_id from tname where profile_id in  a_profile_id).  --- For example : "select profile_id from dao.client where profile_id in (1234,2345) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is using the dynamic SQL, As per my knowledge we need to use the dynamic SQL if we have the table name in a variable.

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f05c35071d1c37f0fb5f8a674aa2b9bb) working code

Query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.de_dup (@a_profile_id NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tname VARCHAR(max)
        ,@id INT
        ,@dynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @matched_tables TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(255));
    DECLARE @matched_profileIds TABLE (profile_id INT);
    DECLARE @profile_ids NVARCHAR(MAX) = @a_profile_id

    INSERT INTO @matched_tables
    SELECT DISTINCT a.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + a.TABLE_NAME AS table_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
    WHERE a.COLUMN_NAME = 'profile_id'

    WHILE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM @matched_tables
            )
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @tname = [Name]
        FROM @matched_tables

        SET @dynamicSQL = CONCAT (
                'select profile_id from '
                ,@tname
                ,' WHERE '
                ,''','
                ,@profile_ids
                ,','''
                ,' LIKE '
                ,'''%,'
                ,''''
                ,' + CAST(profile_id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '
                ,''',%'
                ,''''
                )

        PRINT @dynamicSQL;

        INSERT INTO @matched_profileIds
        EXEC (@dynamicSQL)

        DELETE
        FROM @matched_tables
        WHERE [Name] = @tname
    END

    SELECT *
    FROM @matched_profileIds
END
```

> Dynamic SQL that gets formed is
>
> SELECT profile_id
> FROM dbo.TestTable
> WHERE ',123,456,789,1011,1213,' LIKE '%,' + CAST(profile_id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ',%'

Answer (score 1):

So I have solved a similar issue with a table-valued function called `Split`. It splits a delimited list into rows in a table, which you can then `JOIN` or use as a subquery in your code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @char_array varchar(500), @delimiter char(1)
)
RETURNS 
@parsed_array table
(
    Parsed varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @parsed varchar(50), @pos int

    SET @char_array = LTRIM(RTRIM(@char_array))+ @delimiter
    SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @char_array, 1)

    IF REPLACE(@char_array, @delimiter, '') <> ''
    BEGIN
        WHILE @pos > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @parsed = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@char_array, @pos - 1)))
            IF @parsed <> ''
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @parsed_array (Parsed) 
                VALUES (@parsed)
            END
            SET @char_array = RIGHT(@char_array, LEN(@char_array) - @pos)
            SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @char_array, 1)
        END
    END 
    RETURN
END
GO
```

You would use it like so

```
SELECT f.Parsed INTO #s FROM dbo.Split(@a_profile_id, ',') f;
```

Then in your query (only the relevant part for brevity)

```
select profile_id from @tname where profile_id in(select Parsed from #s);
```

I left out the `set @id=` because that will produce unpredictable results for the value of `@id` if the select statement returns multiple results. But you indicated this is not the actual code anyway so...

Disclaimer: I got the meat of the Split function from someone else online. If I could remember who I would attribute it properly.

Comment: You can use `STRING_SPLIT` if your sql-server version is 2016+

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty thanks, that built-in function is better than the ancient one I have been using!